# Formula field for Date Salesforce.com

Tags: salesforce

I am having a field "L_Date". I want to create a formula field for the report that filters out and gives me only that L_Date that is in the past 18 months starting from today in Salesforce.com.

I am not able to do it for the past 18 months.
How can I achieve this? Can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly.

```
( (TODAY() - L_Date__c) > 18 * 31
```

TODAY() - L_Date__c Gives you the difference between today date and L_Date__c assuming L_Date__c is a date field (if its DateTime use NOW() instead ) . The type of formula can be Boolean or number and then filter by > 18 * 31 in the report.